# Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter

```
 var wfa_res = await CallApi().getData('waiting_for_approval/waiting_approval_list/'+widget.username+'/'+'0/requisition');
 var wfa_res_body = json.decode(wfa_res.body);
```

in widget

```
for(var my_index = 0; my_index < wfa_res_body.length; my_index++)
    Container(
        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(5,5,5,5),
        // child: Text('design'),
        child: Text(approvalInfo != null?approvalInfo['page_data'][my_index]['requisition_code']:''),
      ),
```

error 
Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

Comment: when i set int value instead wfa_res_body.length then work fine!!!
what is the problem ? please help me.

Comment: wfa_res.body could be basically empty. Have you checked it by printing or debugging?

Comment: @ZahidTekbaş yes it have value. when i create hot reload the loop work fine but when i go by navigation then occurred this error.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Actually the api response was too slow. right now i set a loader. and working fine. Thanks to all for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your widget is getting build before async method is completed.
Try using future builder e.g.

Your method :

```
Future yourMethodName() async {
 var wfa_res = await CallApi().getData('waiting_for_approval/waiting_approval_list/'+widget.username+'/'+'0/requisition');
var wfa_res_body = json.decode(wfa_res.body);
return wfa_res_body;
}
```

Future Builder :

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: yourMethodName(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    // after getting data from api
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Actually the api response was too slow. right now i set a loader. and working fine. Thanks to all for answer.